# Exclude maven-compiler-plugin from project.pom

Tags: java, c++, maven-3

I am learning maven right now and intend to use it in a C++ project.

I wrote some plugins for building and testing and they worked reasonably well. However, every time the default java compiler still runs even I do not have any java source files.

Since this project does not use any java-specific features *(except xunit reporting)*, I want to remove the default plugins completely and use the ones I wrote. Is that possible?

Comment: You have to define your own [life cycle which is possible within a plugin](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/writing-plugins-sect-plugins-lifecycle.html) . May be you can share them on Github etc. Apart from that i would suggest to take a look at the http://maven-nar.github.io/

Comment: I set each plugin's phase to "none" and they stopped running. I will take a look at the chapter you pointed. We already have a mature C++ build system that does the build and testing, so the plugins I wrote are simply wrappers.